# How to query relationships of neo4j with custom query with cypher using Grandstack?

Tags: neo4j, graphql, cypher, grandstack

I have these models :

```
type User {
  userId: ID!
  mail: String!
  password: String! @private
  meals: [Meal!] @relationship(type: "IN_MEALS", direction: OUT)
}

type Meal {
  name: String!
  createdBy: User! @relationship(type: "IN_MEALS", direction: IN)
}
```

The relationship is made in neo4j and when I query all users but when I use this custom query for the custom users, meals are defined as null I don't know why

```
type Query {
  currentUser: User
    @cypher(
      statement: """
      MATCH (u:User {userId: $auth.jwt.userId})
      OPTIONAL MATCH (u)-[r:IN_MEALS]->(m:Meal)
      RETURN u,r,m  
      """
    )
}
```

When I do this query in graphql

```
{
  currentUser {
    userId
    mail
    meals {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

It tells me that meals are null but they are not ...

```
{
  "data": {
    "currentUser": {
      "userId": "02e7b50a-1a51-4d3b-b26b-57ed08d89c5a",
      "mail": "mak@gmail.com",
      "meals": null
    }
  }
}
```

I know that by looking into my neo4j database and also because when I query all users

```
{
  users {
    mail
    meals {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

I can see the values in meals :

```
{
  "data": {
    "users": [
      {
        "mail": "mak@gmail.com",
        "meals": [
          {
            "name": "frites"
          },
          {
            "name": "mcdo"
          },
          {
            "name": "sushi"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you only need to provide the toplevel node and then the GRAND stack will handle fetching additional relationships etc. The [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/graphql-manual/current/type-definitions/cypher/) is not so clear unfortunately it seems. Try using:

```
type Query {
  currentUser: User
    @cypher(
      statement: """
      MATCH (u:User {userId: $auth.jwt.userId})
      RETURN u  
      """
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But yhat's exactly what I had at first and it doesn't work either ...  I have "meals": null

But when I look at my graph or when I query all users, I can see meals is not null for this user

Comment: But you get user id?

Comment: Yes I get all the other informations, I edited my post so you can see

Comment: this looks like a bug, I would report this directly to GH.

Comment: Alright thanks will do! :)